# DirectX App won't draw

Tags: c, visual-c++, directx, directx-11

i've set up a directx engine and everything seems fine, but it won't show me the object that it needs to draw and i can't find where the problem lies. i have searched through the code with my tutorial engine but it still won't work. Can anyone see the problem in my code? Thank for the help already. ps. don't worry about the header file it all works, only this file doesn't.

```
#include "AppFramework.h"

struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

struct CBUFFER{ XMMATRIX Final; };

class BoxApp : public Framework_App
{
public:
    BoxApp(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    ~BoxApp();

bool Init();
void OnResize();
void UpdateScene(float dt);
void DrawScene();

void OnMouseDown(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y);
void OnMouseUp(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y);
void OnMouseMove(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y);

private:
    void BuildGeometryBuffers();
    void BuildFX();

private:
    ID3D11Buffer* mBoxVB;
    ID3D11Buffer* mBoxIB;
    ID3D11Buffer* mBoxCB;
    ID3D11VertexShader* pVS;
    ID3D11PixelShader* pPS;

ID3D11InputLayout* mInputLayout;

XMFLOAT4X4 mWorld;
XMFLOAT4X4 mView;
XMFLOAT4X4 mProj;

float mTheta;
float mPhi;
float mRadius;

POINT mLastMousePos;
};
int WINAPI Main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
    PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    BoxApp theApp(hInstance);

    if (!theApp.Init())
        return 0;

    return theApp.App_Run();
}

BoxApp::BoxApp(HINSTANCE hInstance)
: Framework_App(hInstance), mBoxVB(0), mBoxIB(0), pVS(0), pPS(0), mInputLayout(0),
mTheta(1.5f*MathTools::HalfTau), mPhi(0.25f*MathTools::HalfTau), mRadius(5.0f)
{
mLastMousePos.x = 0;
mLastMousePos.y = 0;

XMMATRIX I = XMMatrixIdentity();
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mWorld, I);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mView, I);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mProj, I);
}

BoxApp::~BoxApp()
{
    ReleaseCOM(mBoxVB);
    ReleaseCOM(mBoxIB);
    ReleaseCOM(mBoxCB);
    ReleaseCOM(pVS);
    ReleaseCOM(pPS);
    ReleaseCOM(mInputLayout);




  }
    bool BoxApp::Init()
    {
        if (!Framework_App::App_Init())
            return false;

        BuildGeometryBuffers();
        BuildFX();
return true;
}
void BoxApp::OnResize()
{
    Framework_App::OnResize();

    XMMATRIX P = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.25f*MathTools::HalfTau, AspectRatio(), 1.0f, 1000.0f);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mProj, P);
}
void BoxApp::UpdateScene(float dt)
{
    float x = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*cosf(mTheta);
    float z = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*sinf(mTheta);
    float y = mRadius*cosf(mPhi);

    // Build the view matrix.
    XMVECTOR pos = XMVectorSet(x, y, z, 1.0f);
    XMVECTOR target = XMVectorZero();
    XMVECTOR up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(pos, target, up);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mView, V);
}

void BoxApp::DrawScene()
{
    MainDevContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mRenderTargetView, reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&Colors::LightSteelBlue));
    MainDevContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

MainDevContext->IASetInputLayout(mInputLayout);
MainDevContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
UINT offset = 0;
MainDevContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mBoxVB, &stride, &offset);
MainDevContext->IASetIndexBuffer(mBoxIB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

XMMATRIX world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mWorld);
XMMATRIX view = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mView);
XMMATRIX proj = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mProj);
XMMATRIX worldViewProj = world*view*proj;

CBUFFER cBuffer;
cBuffer.Final = worldViewProj;

MainDevContext->UpdateSubresource(mBoxCB, 0, 0, &cBuffer, 0, 0);
MainDevContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);

mSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}

void BoxApp::OnMouseDown(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    mLastMousePos.x = x;
    mLastMousePos.y = y;

    SetCapture(FrmeWrkMainWnd);
}

void BoxApp::OnMouseUp(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    ReleaseCapture();
}
void BoxApp::OnMouseMove(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    if ((btnState & MK_LBUTTON) != 0)
    {
        // Make each pixel correspond to a quarter of a degree.
        float dx = XMConvertToRadians(0.25f*static_cast<float>(x - mLastMousePos.x));
        float dy = XMConvertToRadians(0.25f*static_cast<float>(y - mLastMousePos.y));

        // Update angles based on input to orbit camera around box.
        mTheta += dx;
        mPhi += dy;

        // Restrict the angle mPhi.
        mPhi = MathTools::Clamp(mPhi, 0.1f, MathTools::HalfTau - 0.1f);
    }
    else if ((btnState & MK_RBUTTON) != 0)
    {
        // Make each pixel correspond to 0.005 unit in the scene.
        float dx = 0.005f*static_cast<float>(x - mLastMousePos.x);
        float dy = 0.005f*static_cast<float>(y - mLastMousePos.y);

        // Update the camera radius based on input.
        mRadius += dx - dy;

        // Restrict the radius.
        mRadius = MathTools::Clamp(mRadius, 3.0f, 15.0f);
    }

    mLastMousePos.x = x;
    mLastMousePos.y = y;
}
void BoxApp::BuildGeometryBuffers()
{
    // Create vertex buffer
    Vertex vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::White },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Black },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Red },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Green },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Blue },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Cyan },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Magneta }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex)* 8;
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
    vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    vinitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    MainD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mBoxVB);

// Create the index buffer

UINT indices[] = {
    // front face
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,

    // back face
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 7, 6,

    // left face
    4, 5, 1,
    4, 1, 0,

    // right face
    3, 2, 6,
    3, 6, 7,

    // top face
    1, 5, 6,
    1, 6, 2,

    // bottom face
    4, 0, 3,
    4, 3, 7
};

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* 36;
ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
MainD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &mBoxIB);
}
void BoxApp::BuildFX()
{

ID3D10Blob* VS;
ID3D10Blob* PS;
D3DX11CompileFromFile((LPSTR)"mColor.shader",0,0, "VSshader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile((LPSTR)"mColor.shader", 0, 0, "PSshader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);
MainD3DDevice->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
MainD3DDevice->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);
MainDevContext->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
MainDevContext->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexDesc[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};
MainD3DDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertexDesc, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize() ,&mInputLayout);
MainDevContext->IASetInputLayout(mInputLayout);
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = 176;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;

MainD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &mBoxCB);
MainDevContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &mBoxCB);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure all the calls are succeeding? Try adding some error checking and handling code.  Also the literal `bd.ByteWidth = 176` looks suspicious, possibly suggesting a mismatch in constant buffer declaration between your C++ code and your HLSL code.

Comment: I've notices a small problem with my code, my 'D3DX11CompileFromFile' function wasn't matching my HLSL code but any problems with the HLSL i couldn't find.

Comment: I've found i new error, it seems my application doesn't draw my thing because it's running another app. since my project does consist of multiple cpp's it seems it's that one but not my new one. now it gives an error that it can't find an entry point.

Comment: I've managed to solve some errors but now all the screen is producing is the half of it with color, further it only works only half of the time. I think it has to do with the bd.bytewith. i've given it the sizeof the constant buffer but i don't really know how i get right.

Comment: I think I see your issue. Try replacing the cbuffer's `XMMATRIX` member with an `XMFLOAT4X4`. Also, use `sizeof(CBUFFER)` in your constant buffer so it gets the true size (which should be 16 bytes, but don't rely on that). also, the backtick allows for inline code formatting (`).

Comment: Thanks the help, i've already solved al my problems with the code. But because of this my code is a little bit more optimized. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looking at your code you aren't using using Effects, even though the code reminds me from a DX Book I have, but without the Effects part ("3D Game Programming with DirectX 11").

Back to topic, as your not using effects, you have to transpose your wvp matrix. Effects does that automatically for you, so you don't have to do it. Also, why do you store your wvp matrix in a struct? You don't have to, but if you need it...

For the `bd.ByteWidth = 176;` you should better use `bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4)` (only if you have only 1 float4x4 matrix in it ;D). The advantage of this is it *always* give accurate results.

If you didn't already find the error, try this ;)

Hoped I helped

Comment: It all works fine now. Thank you. PS. This code is adapted from that book.

Comment: I knew that ;D I'm using it all the time that's why ;)

Comment: Are you experienced in this? I would love to learn more about the whole platform and how it exactly works, because although i've gatherd a lot of information and i'm stil gathering. I would love to learn some more things about it.

Comment: I can't say I'm experienced, as I also just started (August 2014). But I made a lot of research in that topic, so you can just ask me any basic rendering stuff like drawing a cube ;D

Comment: Okay, i will certainly when i have a question.